# Tomcat don't work in Mac (Conflict ?)

Tags: java, macos, tomcat7, tomcat8

Good evening,
I install Tomcat 8 on my MacBook Pro but at the launch of the latter I have several errors. I don't use Eclipse, just start server tomcat in my computer and look the homepage tomcat.

I think there is a conflict between .jar but I do not know where.
I have to add the path:
`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

The Logs :

```
17-Aug-2015 23:24:32.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:32.311 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Aug-2015 23:24:32.370 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Aug-2015 23:24:32.421 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Arrêt du service Catalina
17-Aug-2015 23:24:32.423 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Aug-2015 23:24:32.426 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Aug-2015 23:24:32.427 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Aug-2015 23:24:32.427 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.660 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.662 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jul 1 2015 20:19:55 UTC
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.662 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.24.0
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.662 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.662 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.10.3
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0-b132
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.663 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Library/Tomcat/conf/logging.properties
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Tomcat/endorsed
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Library/Tomcat
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Library/Tomcat
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Library/Tomcat/temp
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/jeremy/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.821 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.852 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.855 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.859 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 586 ms
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.884 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Démarrage du service Catalina
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.885 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.901 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/docs de l'application web
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.949 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.949 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.950 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [j2ee_web_services_1_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.950 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.950 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.950 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.951 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-app_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.951 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-fragment_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.951 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-common_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.951 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_6.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.952 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [jsp_2_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.952 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.955 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.955 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-app_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.955 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-fragment_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.956 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-common_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.956 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_7.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.956 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [jsp_2_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.957 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:39.957 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.055 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1872)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.057 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Erreur lors du déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/docs de l'application web
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.059 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/docs has finished in 157 ms
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.060 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/examples de l'application web
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.096 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1872)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.096 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Erreur lors du déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/examples de l'application web
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.097 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/examples has finished in 38 ms
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.097 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/host-manager de l'application web
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.110 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/host-manager]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1872)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.110 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Erreur lors du déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/host-manager de l'application web
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/host-manager]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.110 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/host-manager has finished in 13 ms
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.111 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/manager de l'application web
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.123 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/manager]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1872)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.124 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Erreur lors du déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/manager de l'application web
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/manager]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.124 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/manager has finished in 14 ms
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.124 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/ROOT de l'application web
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.132 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1872)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.133 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Erreur lors du déploiement du répertoire /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/ROOT de l'application web
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.133 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/ROOT has finished in 9 ms
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.136 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.143 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Aug-2015 23:24:40.144 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 284 ms
```

Thx all for answers.

Comment: are you trying to start TomCat without any embedded app?

Comment: Yes, i try with this command : /Library/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh in terminal and I have a white page in localhost:8080. The Log in the post are the result.

Comment: a white page or 404 error?

Comment: White page but in browser log I have a error 404. 
All exception is okay ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getContextPath()Ljava/lang/String;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611777/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext-getcontextpathljava) NB: that was the first google result for your stacktrace..

Comment: white page is ok, but exceptions are not (not always), is this log only from starting the server or did u executed other commands there?

Comment: RC : I don't use Eclipse, I just try to start Tomcat and look the homepage. 
Mastah : Yes, only when I start the server.

Comment: /Library/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/Tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.

Comment: The problem looks to be because pre-3.0 servlet API classes are being found instead of the legit Tomcat 8 ones. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437117/tomcat-newbie-illegalstateexception-on-new-installation - could there be any unwanted extra JAR files in the Tomcat install directory?

Comment: I don't have extra JAR Files and I don't have Javaee-api.jar file.

Comment: I have a Bonita application on my Mac. There is Tomcat Folder, a conflict with it's possible ?

Comment: Anybody ? Always the same problem.